# OpenCart install on bluehost getting 5.2+ required

Tags: php, bluehost, opencart

I'm getting `PHP 5.2+ required` when installing OpenCart on Bluehost.

Bluehost runs PHP 5.2.9. Searching the forums I see others running OpenCart successfully on this version.

Where do I start to try and get opencart up and running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue

- List item
- Log into cPanel
- Click `Software / Services`
- Click `PHP Config`
- Select `PHP5`
- Save your changes

Answer (score 2):

First of all, 5.2.9 is definitly 5.2+ (5.2+ means at least 5.2 ; 5.2.9 is 5.2 with fixes ;-) )

You could try to check the version of PHP you have on your hosting service, creating a page that only contains

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

This post could interest you, too : [Bluehost php5 or php4 your choice](http://www.bluehostreview.org/bluehost-php5-or-php4-your-choice) ; either you have to go through their support, or maybe you have some option in your administration panel, to choose between PHP 4 (which is way outdated... it's a shame if it's still the default version) and PHP 5 ?

Answer (score 1):

upload a php file with the following code in it to your webroot and open it, it will tell you which version of php is really running. There is a chance that php wasn't upgraded on the box you are on.

```
<? 
echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();
```